# Getting pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).* error. Solution?

Tags: python, pysimplegui, pytube

I'm getting the already mentioned error when I run this part of the code:

```
def downlad_playlist(listurl, destination, only_audio = True):
    list_url = Playlist(listurl)

    print(f'Downloading: {list_url.title}')
    for url in list_url.video_urls:
        vid_url = YouTube(url)
        window["-DOWNLOAD_TEXT-"].update("Downloading: " + vid_url.title)
        window.refresh()
        vid_url.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
        # try:
        video = vid_url.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        out_file = video.download(output_path=destination)
```

The full error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gamer\Desktop\yt-py\yt_downloaderV3.py", line 111, in <module>
    download_video(values["-YOUTUBE_URL-"], values["-SAVE_LOCATION-"])
  File "C:\Users\gamer\Desktop\yt-py\yt_downloaderV3.py", line 36, in download_video
    yt = YouTube(url)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gamer\Desktop\yt-py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gamer\Desktop\yt-py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gamer\Desktop\yt-py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

I'm using pysimplegui for the GUI.

The URL is correct an the code worked well in an other project, so I don't know why it gives an error.

Probably I messed up something simple, but I can't find it, so I'm asking for help here.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, so no one can give you a definitive answer. Please see these two articles:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

The error that you're encountering means that you *must. not.* blindly trust your own assertion that the URL is correct. Please inspect and (if necessary) show the actual data that you're passing in.

Comment: You show an error with a regular expression but do not provide the regular expression code. Impossible to help with info given.

Comment: Print each URL before passing it to `YouTube(url)`. What is the last URL printed before the error?